# How to append a content from one file into a second file

Tags: unix, awk, sed

How can I append a content of a  file `Apple.txt` into another file `Fruit.txt`,it needs to be At the of the second line in that file.

Also I need to append the current date at the end of the first line.

Here are the files:

```
Apple.txt
44
```

```
Fruit.txt
Date,  12/08,12/09
Apple, 23,55
Banana, 33,02
```

Here is the output that I need:

```
Fruit.txt
Date,  12/08,12/09,12/10
Apple, 23,55,44
Banana, 33,02
```

Thank you,

Paul

Comment: Do you even know `cat` command ?

Comment: I know very little,so any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Search about `concatenation cat unix`, there's TONS of how to

Comment: Where does `12/10` come from?

Comment: `cat` would be the solution to the problem stated in the Subject line, but not to the actual problem described in the text.

Comment: 12/10 is the current date that i need to append.

Comment: Your question is too vague. Even if a solution is provided, chances are it will not work with your data set. Also, try providing complete information in your question instead of adding details in the comments.

Comment: I second what @jaypalsingh said - start again and THINK a bit about what you're saying and what we would need to know to be able to help you before posting.

Comment: @jaypalsingh Ah, I thought you were asking "Did you think before posting". Yes, welcome back!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give  you some to start.

```
awk -F, -vd=$(date "+%m/%d") 'FNR==NR {a=$1;next} FNR==1 {$0=$0 FS d} $1~/Apple/ {$0=$0 FS a}1' Apple.txt Fruit.txt
Date,  12/08,12/09,12/10
Apple, 23,55,44
Banana, 33,02
```

To get update original file add `> tmp && mv tmp Fruit.txt` after the `awk` line